# Unknown constructor 'Name.Name(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)' when removing RecordSetVar

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button, standardcontroller

I am attempting to convert my page to work from List View button into Detail Page button.

When I attempt to remove the recordsetvar, I get the mentioned error.

```
Unknown constructor 'AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor.AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
```

Below are pieces of code:

VF

```
<apex:page standardController="Line_del__c" recordSetVar="recrec" extensions="AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor">
```

Apex

```
  public with sharing class AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor{
    Public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList{get;set;}
    public AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      mycon = controller;
      Selectedmeters = mycon.getSelected();
    }
    public List<sobject> Selectedmeters {get; set;} 
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mycon; 
   Public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj(){
      List<electricity_meter__c> MeterList = [Select id,name,AQ__c,meter_details__c from electricity_meter__c where Linked_Monitor_Line__c in: SelectedMeters];
```

The last line is where I need to use my ID (should be Linked_Monitor_Line__c=SelectedMeters). I know I can get the Id by doing something like: Id recordId = standardController.getId(); but I realize in this case it's different?

Comment: Please be more specific - I currently can't understand what you want to achieve. Could you provide us with more data or edit your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Building a Controller Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) I think you should have a constructor with ApexPages.StandardController as a parameter:

```
public with sharing class AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor{
    Public List<WrapperClassEx> WrapperList{get;set;}
    public AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      // this is new constructor which should fix your problem
    }
    public AddBasketGasQuoteFromMonitor(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
      mycon = controller;
      Selectedmeters = mycon.getSelected();
    }
    public List<sobject> Selectedmeters {get; set;} 
    ApexPages.StandardSetController mycon; 
   Public List<WrapperClassEx> getwrapperObj(){
      List<electricity_meter__c> MeterList = [Select id,name,AQ__c,meter_details__c from electricity_meter__c where Linked_Monitor_Line__c in: SelectedMeters];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem completely! Can you just explain what I have done here?

Comment: I think you can still use your controller for set of data. But sfdc insist on constructor with standard controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using `recordSetVar` then your Controller Extension constructor needs to take an `ApexPages.StandardController` argument rather than a `ApexPages.StandardSetController` argument.

See the documentation [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) for more information.

> A controller extension is any Apex class containing a constructor that takes a single argument of type `ApexPages.StandardController` or *CustomControllerName*, where *CustomControllerName* is the name of a custom controller you want to extend.

You can then get the current record using the `StandardController.getRecord()` method which is documented [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm).

> **getRecord()**
>   Returns the record that is currently in context, based on the value of the id query string parameter in the Visualforce page URL.